# Extracting data using rails query from a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have users table, books table and books_users join table. In the users_controller.rb I am trying extract the users who have filtered_books. Please help me to resolve that problem.

user.rb

```
has_many :books_users, dependent: :destroy
has_and_belongs_to_many :books, join_table: :books_users
```

book.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

books_user.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :book
```

users_controller.rb

```
def filter_users
 @filtered_books = Fiction.find(params[:ID]).books
 @users = **I want only those users who have filtered_books**
end
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with this question that need to be addressed first. `has_and_belongs_to_many` does not use a join model, so if you are using HABTM `BooksUser` is completely superflous. Then you just spring `Fiction` on us without telling us anything about the relation or even what you're trying to accomplish with it. If its an attempt to do categorization you missed the mark.

Comment: Also `params[:ID]` != `params[:id]`. Case matters in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` does not actually use a join model. What you are looking for is `has_many through:`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_users
  has_many :books, through: :book_users
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_users
  has_many :users, through: :book_users
end

class BookUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If you want to add categories to books you would do it by adding a Category model and another join table. Not by creating a `Fiction` model which will just create a crazy amount of code duplication if you want multiple categories.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_users
  has_many :users, through: :book_users
  has_many :book_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :book_categories
end

class BookCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_categories
  has_many :books, through: :book_categories
end
```

If you want to query for users that follow a certain book you can do it by using an inner join with a condition on books:

```
User.joins(:books)
    .where(books: { title: 'Lord Of The Rings' })
```

If you want to get books that have a certain category:

```
Book.joins(:categories)
    .where(categories: { name: 'Fiction' })
```

Then for the grand finale - to query users with a relation to at least one book that's categorized with "Fiction" you would do:

```
User.joins(books: :categories)
    .where(categories: { name: 'Fiction' })

# or if you have an id 
User.joins(books: :categories)
    .where(categories: { id: params[:category_id] })
```

You can also add an indirect association that lets you go straight from categories to users:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :users, though: :books
end

category = Category.includes(:users)
                   .find(params[:id])
users = category.users
```

See:

- [The has_many :through Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
- [Joining nested assocations.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level)
- [Specifying Conditions on Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)

Answer (score -1):

From looking at the code i am assuming that `Book` model has `fiction_id` as well because of the `has_many` association shown in this line `Fiction.find(params[:ID]).books`. There could be two approaches achieve this. First one could be that you use `@filtered_books` variable and extract users from it like `@filtered_books.collect {|b| b.users}.flatten` to extract all the users. Second approach could be through associations using `fiction_id` which could be something like `User.joins(:books).where(books: {id: @filtererd_books.pluck(:id)})`

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this that don't involve pulling everything out of the database and turning it into an array of ids. This is not a good approach.

Comment: Pluck also won't work here as its a query method and you already mangled it into an array by using `collect`. You would have to do `.map(&:id)`.